# Mode function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was trying to use the mode function in matlab over an array of numbers (some negative negative present in this array). 
But when I do

mode(this_array)

i get "Attempted to access mode(-1); index must be a positive integer or logical".

The following is my piece of code:

```
for row=1:K,
    ind = index(row);
    label = trY(ind);
    i = i + 1;
end % for

y = mode(label); // gives error esp. when the array contains only one negative value
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good chance that you have a variable named `mode` in your program.